# dynamically loading a dll that uses the applications methods

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, visual-studio-2015

I want to change and test my dll function build for an application without constantly closing and starting the application itself, which takes a lot of time. Hence I build a calling dll for the application to load, and another testing dll (which i load dynamically), where I can change my testing function in real time, without closing the application.
The application loads automatically the calling dll, wherein I can dynamically load my testing dll and call an empty function succesfully :

calling dll:

```
typedef void(__stdcall *test_func)(void);
HINSTANCE hdl = LoadLibraryA("C:\\testingfunction.dll");
test_func func = (test_func) GetProcAddress(hdl, "?testingfunc@@YAXXZ");
func();
```

In the testing function dll I have:
testingfunction.h

```
#define DLL_API _declspec(dllexport)
DLL_API void __stdcall testingfunc();
```

testingfunction.cpp

```
DLL_API void __stdcall testingfunc()
{
    double a = 3 * 4.2;
    //PlugIn::gResultOut << "  ...I am alive... " << std::endl;

return;
}
```

So if the printing line is commented out, the function works in the application, meaning it does not crash. But when I uncomment the printing line, the application crashes. It seems I cannot use the methods and functions of the application itself.
How would I fix this? Do I need to use `__declspec(dllimport)`, and if so, how?

thanks!

Comment: Is the testing DLL statically linked to the EXE file? How is `PlugIn::gResultOut` created, and when?  The calling DLL will likely have to pass a pointer to a valid `gResultOut` object to the testing DLL at runtime after loading it dynamically. You really shouldn't be passing objects over the DLL boundary to begin with, and certainly not static linking them.  Pass around C-style function pointers instead, or abstract interfaces.

Comment: Thank you Remy for your answer. I think I may be out of my depths here. I built the dll against the sdk the application company has provided. I assume it is not linked to the exe file, because vs2015 has no information about the paths of the application itself. I put the testingfunc() function inside the main Plugin class as a virtual function but the application still crashes when using the gResultOut function. It calculates the "a" variable correctly though.... The gResultOut function works correctly when using in the calling dll, but not when using it from the testing DLL .

Comment: Additionally, even if I define the exported function in the testing DLL as: double _declspec(dllexport) __stdcall testingfunc(); .  When using dumpbin on the DLL, I get ?testingfunc@@YANXZ = ?testingfunc@@YANXZ (double __cdecl testingfunc(void)). Why is the calling convention changed from __stdcall to  __cdecl?